# Unable to play youtube videos in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, video, youtube

As seen here in the consoles this is my trying to manually get the videos working, however on normal page load you would only see the first error:

[image]

I am just using the standard iframe supplied by youtube to get this working. I have seen it work, but now it appears to have packed in and just wonder render.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="255" frameborder="0" type="text/html" id="ytplayer" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?list=PLwC71vzP2zJEj0SeuP2Sn2dUU9DaKxliU&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

What makes me more confused is, the video plays in hydration mode offered by phonegap, but not in production mode...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

App
    
        app
    
    
        PhoneGap Team

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TtoEkhwzjVorel=0&amp;showinfo=0&quot" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"  style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;width:100%;height:115%;"></iframe>
```

I think this might be helpful for you.